# TRy ubuntu just for a week and after that bring it back to its earlier state. Is it possible?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, live-cd, debian

So, My dad is not at home and i want to try ubuntu. IS this possible to use ubuntu for  a week and after that, bring everything normal. {remove the grub, remove the partiton done, etc.}
I know that we can use Live Ubuntu but it is very slow on both CD and USB.

Answer (score 1):

Is your computer running Windows and you want to try Ubuntu in dual-boot mode?  If so, make a disk image of the complete hard drive using something like [Macrium Reflect Free Edition](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx).  Install Ubuntu in side-by-side mode (or whatever the current distro calls dual-boot).  At the end of your week of dual-boot usage, use Macrium Reflect to restore the disk image.  This will bring your system back exactly to the point before you installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and create a virtual machine to run Ubuntu. After you are done, simply delete the virtual machine and uninstall Virtual Box.